# Python split string into list with ints, strings and decimals

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Im trying to split

```
dimensions = "M 0 0 C 65 1 130 1 194.6875 0 C 195 17 195 33 194.6875 50 C 130 49 65 49 0 50 C 0 33 0 17 0 0 z"
```

into list form where if I wanted to get `194.6875` I could do

```
print(dimensions[8])
```

Im having trouble converting it to a list since there are multiple types.

Comment: You want the dimensions[8] to be a float or a string ?

Comment: float is what im going for

Comment: If this is an SVG path you're trying to parse, perhaps you want to have a look at https://pypi.org/project/svg.path/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .split() method on a string and pass in the character you want to split on, i.e:

```
dimensions = "M 0 0 C 65 1 130 1 194.6875 0 C 195 17 195 33 194.6875 50 C 130 49 65 49 0 50 C 0 33 0 17 0 0 z"
listDimensions = dimensions.split(' ')
x = float(listDimensions[8])
print(x)
```

After that it is a case of changing the data type of the item you want with something like `str()`, `int()` or `float()`

Answer (score 1):

```
dimensions = "M 0 0 C 65 1 130 1 194.6875 0 C 195 17 195 33 194.6875 50 C 130 49 65 49 0 50 C 0 33 0 17 0 0 z"
dimensions = dimensions.split(" ")
print(float(dimensions[8]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split on space and convert to float the values that are not alphabetic strings

```
dimensions = "M 0 0 C 65 1 130 1 194.6875 0 C 195 17 195 33 194.6875 50 C 130 49 65 49 0 50 C 0 33 0 17 0 0 z"
values = [val if val.isalpha() else float(val) for val in dimensions.split(" ")]

print(values) # ['M', 0.0, 0.0, 'C', 65.0, 1.0, 130.0, 1.0, 194.6875, 0.0, 'C', 195.0, 17.0, 195.0, 33.0, 194.6875, 50.0, 'C', 130.0, 49.0, 65.0, 49.0, 0.0, 50.0, 'C', 0.0, 33.0, 0.0, 17.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'z']
print(values[8], type(values[8])) # 194.6875 <class 'float'>
```